Finding the number of $k$ element subsets of $A$ such that the sum of the elements in is congruent to a fixed integer $L$ mod$P$
Let  $A$ be a set of $p$ elements where $P$  is an odd prime. We are interested in finding the number of $k$ element subsets of $A$ such that the sum of the elements in the subset is congruent to a fixed integer $L$ mod $p$ i.e,$$\sum k\equiv L \ (mod\ p)$$Is there any formula/method for this?
